# How to point to local copy of .crate file of crate from crates.io?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am behind a corporate proxy that won't let me access crates.io from our development hosts.  I have downloaded all the crates I need and have them locally.  The project I am building is from a 3rd party who have provided their own (~100 of them) Cargo.toml files.  How do I override the location of every dependency instead of changing every Cargo.toml to point to my local copy?

I tried adding `paths = [ "path/to/crates" ]` to `~/.cargo/config` & `~/.cargo/config.toml`, but to no avail.  Is it possible or is there an alternative?

I tried this in my `~/.cargo/config.toml`

```
[source]
[source.my-crates]
local-registry = "/absolute/path/to/location/where/i/have/star.crate"
[source.crates-io]
replace-with = "my-crates"
```

However, it doesn't even look like it is being used.  It still looks for crates.io-index

Comment: Sounds like you want [Source Replacement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/source-replacement.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be missing `CARGO_HOME` environment variable.